# httpd.conf always in use, even after killing apache processes?

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I am having the most frustrating time trying to edit my httpd.conf file for Apache server. I've done it numerous times on other machines, but on this one, it says it's always in use. I've killed the Apache service and the Apache monitor process.

Does anyone know what else would use this file? Let me know of any other info you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try the commands fuser or lsof to see/kill the process that uses the file. see this link for some examples (scroll down a bit): http://www.lunarforums.com/vps_hosting_at_lunarpages/useful_linux_scripts_lsof_ps_fuser_netstat-t41474.0.html

Comment: I should have mentioned I'm on Windows 7, sorry for leaving that out.

Comment: I finally figured out what the problem was here. User Access Control on Windows 7 was preventing me from changing the file. I set it to the lowest possible setting, rebooted and can edit the file now. For more details check out this -> http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprosecurity/thread/eccfa252-b00c-47c4-b49b-cf74e60b222a/